# Using ADC AD9057

Tags: adc, analog, noise, signal-processing

I use AD9057 with fpga in my oscilloscope project. Here is the ADC pin-out 
[image: pinout]

I use the following scheme to test ADC:
VREF OUT connected to VREF IN, this gives internal reference voltage +2.5V

Vd +3.3 V

VDD +5 V

Encode - clock signal 3.3V (i have tried different frequencies according to datasheet)

I use constant voltage level from 2V (00000000) to 3V(11111111) according to datasheet (for Vref 2.5V), and i try to see valid bit patterns on D0-D7 pins, but it seems that only noise there.

1.) Is my test valid?

2.) I found a scheme in datasheet

[image: ADC simple scheme from datasheet]

And i don't understand why AIN is blocked with capacitor (how can i measure constant voltage in this case?) In my test i use the same scheme but without this capacitor. Maybe this is the reason of ADC's strange behavior?

Comment: "A" in AIN may stand for "audio", which is also supported by the 1 Vpp input signal.  Even hi-fi audio only goes down to 20 Hz, so the DC level can be discarded.  In fact, it's a good idea to get rid of frequencies that you know aren't in your signal.

Comment: I think it stand for "analog", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same datasheet , indeed, on the same page is the following diagram:
[image]

The diagram you've included above is captioned "capacitively coupled"

Given you're only capacitively coupling a DC signal you should only see "noise".

Comment: Yes i saw this. But why i can't use AIN pin directly without this amplifier, and without capaciator (i mean capaciator on AIN pin in the scheme i included above)?

Comment: The opamp there is just doing the signal inversion. That's why its called _Inverted VIN_. No need for that one.

Comment: @Dzarda Does it mean that i can transfer constant analog signal directly to the AIN without any extra elements?

Comment: Well, you might be. The datasheet says it's got input resistance of 150kOhm, which is pretty high. Not quite as high as I would expect though. That means, if you have a signal that has _high output impedance_, you get noise. Take a look here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications Particularly Unity-gain Buffer.

Comment: @Dzarda I think big source output impedance is not my case.

Comment: Then I dont know.

Comment: You can drive the input directly but keep in mind that it will only digitize values that are around 2.5V +/- 0.5 V.  So from 2.0 V to 3.0 V range and will limit out beyond those ranges.  Depending upon your circuit you can do a AC couple and DC restore (with clamping to a reference).  You can modify the VRef_in a bit but it seems to like to be around the 2.5 volt range.